# debugging under many custom domains

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm developing a web app that will be accessed under various urls and of course i need to test it under circumstances as close to reality as possible. so the question here is: `How can i set VS 2013 so i can debug my application using "a.com", "b.com" and "c.com"?` instead of localhost...

Details:

- I'm developing a ASP.Net MVC 5 + Web Api
- Currently it's running atop of IIS 8 (not express)
- Currently it's running on: `http://localhost/app1` but i want to run it at the root `http://localhost/`

Comment: In what enviorment is your code running and what does it do? Is it a ASP.net website? Is it a SelfHosted WCF Service exposed to the internet? Depending on what you are doing how you solve the problem you are having is very diffrent. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23744104/edit) and add more details about what kind of program you are writing and how it is being run. Also please show how you are using `localhost` currently, are you talking about the debugger starting and opening `http://localhost/projectName` or are you talking about something else.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ok! updated!

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Visual Studio. It seems to me that once you get to the point where you need to test the different domains, you need a web server that supports the different domains. How about  using IIS Express at that point, along with a hosts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could edit your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file to point your domains to any IP (or IPs) bound to your site.
This would be a machine specific solution - it would only affect the computer on which you edited the hosts file.